# Express PUT endpoint function keeps returning undefined

Tags: postgresql, express, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I am using the Knex and bookshelf libraries for express to write my endpoints.  I'm still fairly new in writing PUT endpoints and the one I am attmpting to write keeps coming back as undefined.  I have my files separated into routes and controllers.

The route is:

```
 app.put('/studentList/:id', (req,res)=>{
         students.editStatus(req.params.id)            
        .then((student) => { res.send(student.attributes) })

  })
```

and the controller is:

```
exports.editStatus=(id)=>{
  console.log(id)
  const fieldToUpdate={status:'in'}
  new Student({id:id})
  .save(fieldToUpdate)
  .then(saved=>{
        console.log(saved)
        return saved;
  }).catch(err=>{
        console.log(err)
  })
```

}

I'm trying to get the edited student information sent back up to the front end, but I keep getting -

> Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

I've console logged saved inside the editStatus function and it shows

> 

```
ModelBase {
  attributes: { id: '5', status: 'in' },
  _previousAttributes: { id: '5', status: 'in' },
  changed: {},
  relations: {},
  cid: 'c2',
  id: '5',
  _knex: null }
```

But that value does not seem to be getting out of the function

Comment: You need to return the Promise that's returned by calling `save()` inside `editStatus` in order to properly chain the Promises.

Comment: thanks, I added a return before new Student and it works now!

Comment: Also, you shouldn't send `model.attributes` directly in the response unless you know exactly that you need it. You can omit the `.attributes` part and the model will be properly serialized.